# Setting the token-validitys-seconds of RememberMe Dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, remember-me

Using Spring, I've declared a RememberMe bean in my XML:

```
<security:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
      ..... 
            <security:remember-me 
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>

</security:http>
```

As far as I understand, this causes **PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices** because data-source is declared.
I can ass also set '*token-validity-seconds*', but life are more complicated than this... I want to set the validity **dynamically**.

How can I do this? how can i "autowire" this bean, or how can I get it using the "*context.getBean()*"? I do not know the name of this bean... Do I have to declare it differently?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

All you have to do is autowiring the remember-me service, and set the token validity:

```
@Autowired
private AbstractRememberMeServices rememberMeService;
```

and in your code, where-ever needed:

```
rememberMeService.setTokenValiditySeconds(X);
```